# Is it possible to "cheat" items into my inventory in survival mode?

Tags: cheats, junon.io

There is a game I enjoy called junon.io, and I want to be able to cheat in items so I can get a bit more enjoyment out of certain maps.
I want to use the chrome inspect console, but I don't know what code would give me items.
It is mostly fun but some maps get stale after a while.

I will not be using this for multiplayer, only for the survival mode.

Comment: This wiki page seems relevant: https://junonio.fandom.com/wiki/Help_(command) but it seems to be about in game use of the commands, not using a developer console in Chrome.  Does that work though?

Comment: That is for if you are hosting a creative server. I wish to get items that are normally unobtainable/scarce in survival mode. Thank you for the advice tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually possible. You can export your save and edit it.
The save file is compressed, so you would need to extract it before you edit it. Use an archiver like 7-zip to extract it.

You can view the source of junon.io here: [https://github.com/yomugames/junon/blob/master/packages/junon-common/](https://github.com/yomugames/junon/blob/master/packages/junon-common/world_serializer.js)

I have not found any save-editor for junon.io yet, so you need to figure out how to edit the save yourself.

Comment: could i get a quick guide on how and what to edit please?
I know almost nothing about coding....